# libpng - Reading/Writing both RGB and BGR

Tags: c++, libpng

I have a library that uses libpng to read and write both grayscale and RGB images.  I already have separate C++ types for my BGR and RGB images but until now I've been manually coverting the BGR ones to RGB before saving them to PNG.  Then, when I read, I always read in as RGB.

What I would *like* to do is write and read my images as with as little transformation required as possible.  If I could write out my BGRs *as* BGRs and read them back in that way, that would be ideal.

But the libpng docs confuse me on this matter.  is RGB/BGR information actually saved to the image format itself?  That is, when I open up a PNG image, can I ask libpng if it was RGB or BGR or must I know ahead of time?  If I can, I've missed the function that lets me.

I see functions like png_set_bgr and transform flags like PNG_TRANSFORM_BGR but I'm not sure of the proper way to use them.

Can anyone set me straight?

Comment: From what I understand, PNG only stores RGB. BGR transformations are just for convenience, I'd think (ex: for rasterizing images in windows), since I believe the format strictly stores things in RGB color space.

Comment: I don't know libpng so well but at a glance I believe those transform functions for reading and writing are primarily intended so that on reading, if you want to say, rasterize to a BGR display, you can do that without manually transforming yourself. Then on writing you'd transform back to RGB. As stated in the libpng docs: `PNG files store 3 color pixels in red, green, blue order.` That's exclusively the case as far as I understand, and probably why you don't find any kind of way to extract header info about whether the image uses RGB or BGR, since it's exclusively RGB AFAIK.